# replace abbreviation with corresponding id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dict, a map of language abbreviations to their corresponding ids in database.

```
langs_map = {'ka': 1, 'ru' : 5, 'en':6}
```

And I have pandas dataframe wich has columns like name_lang_ka, name_lang_ru, name_lang_en and address_lang_ka, address_lang_ru, address_lang_en in it.
This map and dataframe columns may vary depending on languages that are enabled.

So what I'm trying to achieve is to form these to column names like : name_lang_1, name_lang_5, name_lang_6 and address_lang_1 address_lang_5 and address_lang_6.
Any kind of help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Use solution in dupe, only need replace inteegrs to strings `langs_map = {k: str(v) for k, v in langs_map.items()}`

Comment: @jezrael good find! In this case however, since the abbreviations are short, regex could be better to avoid replacing characters in `address`, `lang` and `name` (`la` for latin for instance): `df.columns = [re.sub('[^_]+$', lambda x: str(langs_map.get(x.group(0), x.group(0))), c) for c in df.columns]`

Comment: @Tranbi thank you for the reply. I forgot to mention that I also have other columns that contain underscores for example working_hours, opening_time and so on. Your answer works perfectly in case of name and address columns but also affects other columns like so: 'search_langlocation', 'opening_langtime', 'closing_langtime',. Is it possible to specify in regex that after underscore must be only 2 characters or something?

Comment: Yes it's possible but other columns shouldn't be affected as long as the part after the last `_` isn't in `langs_map`